# Paginated report nested in Desktop

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, reportbuilder3.0

I have a pagineted report nested in my Power BI report (to deal with trends without having to import large amounts of data). It works like a charm in Desktop, but when I published it, it behaves strangely. These are me chosen dates:

[Time range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQY2Z.png)

As you can see, it's not reflected in the charts.

[Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPud.png)

The statistics to the right are part of the paginated report as well and they are calculated correctly. It's just those charts...

When I click "Show as table", it shows the right timespan"

[Timespan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGbJ7.png)

It's not always a flat line - sometimes it fixes on the values from one of the events and show it for every event:

[Chart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGIlC.png)

What is going on here and how can I fix this?

Thanks,

Joanna

I tried to republish both paginated report with trends and whole Power BI Desktop report.

Comment: maybe set the Y Axis to be set to intervals of 20 always starting at 0 instead of leaving it as automatic??